# Textbox using password mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am using a text box with Password mode. And inserting the value using encryption. After that while updating the information I have to display the text again using password mode. But While assigning the data It is not displaying it in the textbox. How can I overcome this?

Comment: How are you assigning the data? What database-connection do you use?

Comment: I am using SQL database. I am inserting the data into database after encrypting it. Again I retrieve the data after decrypting it. But I have to display it as *.

For example, I am entering SANTHOSH as input in Textbox. It will display as ********. While inserting the data will be encrypted like a1!@# like this. While retrieving I am getting santhosh from datatable. But I have to display it as ********.

Comment: @susanthosh, have you try this txtbox1.Attributes.Add("value", "yourValue"); ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty simple...

```
txtbox1.Attributes.Add("value", "yourValue");
TextBox_admin_password.Attributes.Add("value", showInfo.password);
```

the first parameter of `Add()` method is Key value and can be any value as desired by user and the second parameter is password that user retrieves from database or any source.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following link :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/ASPNET_Password_TextBox.aspx

Comment: Pretty slick answer, liked it.

Comment: Please don't add link only answers!